# program crash after swapping addresses in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, malloc

I want to create two arrays, therefore I use `malloc` to allocate dynamic storage.

```
    mov rdi, 10
    call malloc
    mov dl, [rax]
    mov [rbx], dl ; <- right here is the problem
    call malloc
```

But my program doesn't actually swap values instead it crashes. `rdx` is `0` after moving `[rax]` in `dl`

[image: registers right before the crash]

What am I doing wrong? I didn't find anything in the www

EDIT:

This would be equivalent C code, I think. Have to say that I never really worked with C before.

```
void create_array(int n) {
    int a[n];
    int b[n];
}
```

Comment: `rbx` is null, where did you set it? Why do you do the copy before you even allocate the second array?

Comment: What exactly is this expected to be swapping?

Comment: I want `[rax]` and `[rbx]` to swap :). Before the code snippet I just set some registers to null because I want to use them later. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: You use `[rbx]` .. what do you want that to be? If it's null that will crash.

Comment: I want my first array to start at `[rbx]`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "start at `[rbx]`".  As noted, `rbx` is zero so you cannot store anything at that address.  Could you show equivalent C code to demonstrate what it is that you want to do?

Comment: If it helps, the C equivalent of your current program is: `char *rax, *rbx, dl; rax = malloc(10); dl = *rax; *rbx = dl; rax = malloc(garbage);`.  You load `dl` with the contents of the uninitialized memory allocated by `malloc`; you dereference the uninitialized pointer `rbx`; and you do not set up a sensible size argument for the second call to `malloc` (the first call can overwrite the value in `rdi`).

Comment: Thank you first of all! So I should first initialize the memory I allocated and then create the second array?

Comment: Sorry I'm really a newbie :(

Comment: But why is it not possible to save anything at `[rbx]`, just because it's 0? I don't get that :(

Comment: Because under an OS you can't randomly write into any memory address, especially not `null` which is deliberately not mapped.

Comment: @Carmastatorsi `rbx` must point at some memory.  There is no memory at address zero.

Comment: The C code in the question post doesn't do anything, it's just some declarations; there's no `malloc` or swapping.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But how would the proper code look like. I was still trying around but didn't manage to get it. :(

Comment: You should describe exactly what you want to do. Use pseudocode if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but I'm guessing that you want to `malloc` two arrays and then swap their first elements, judging by your pseudo C and the comments.

As people have pointed out in the comments, your `rbx` is never set to any actual address, so it contains garbage (or `0`) at that point. Writing to such a location would result in a crash, because it would point to invalid memory. Let me explain.

```
mov rdi, 10
call malloc
```

This is correct (though you could have used `edi` to save a byte). `malloc` takes its first and only argument in `rdi`, and returns in `rax` a pointer to allocated memory. `rax` at this point is the only thing pointing to valid memory.

```
mov dl, [rax]
```

You are now reading the first byte from that allocated memory into `dl`. This, too, is valid. What isn't valid is the next instruction.

```
mov [rbx], dl
```

As mentioned earlier, it doesn't seem that you ever set `rbx` to anything. It's pointing to some random, almost certainly invalid place in memory (or to nowhere). What I think you intended to do is something like this.

```
mov edi, 10
call malloc
mov rbx, rax ; First array in rbx

mov edi, 10
call malloc ; Second array in rax

mov dl, [rax] ; Load byte from second array
mov [rbx], dl ; Store that byte to first array
```

This example doesn't actually do any swapping (I'll leave that as an exercise for you), but it illustrates that `rbx` should point to valid memory before  anything may be written to (or read from) the memory location it contains.

Comment: Wow! I honestly don't know what to say, except thank you 1000 times! Not only that you understood my gibberish, but you explained it very good.

Comment: You should thank the people in the comments section. I merely put together what they said :)